# CSS perspective angle isn't straight

Tags: css, transform

I'm trying to make a website where the scroll "zooms in", using CSS3's `translateZ()`. Each section of the website is a panel with a "window" in it, when you zoom in, you go through this window and approach the next section. Look at the snippet, it'll be clearer what I'm after.

```js
var main = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0]
document.getElementById('scroll').style.height = window.getComputedStyle(main).height.slice(0, -2) * main.getElementsByTagName('section').length;

var has_scrolled = false;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  has_scrolled = true;
})

var navigate = function() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(navigate);
  if (has_scrolled) {
    main.style.transform = "translate3d(-50%, 0, " + (window.pageYOffset) + "px)"
    has_scrolled = false;
  }
};
navigate();
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  letter-spacing: 0.075em;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #000000;
  perspective-origin: center 61.290322581vmin;
  perspective: 100vmin;
}
main {
  height: 100vmin;
  width: 162vmin;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
}
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
section:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0vmin);
}
section:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, -163.157894737vmin);
}
section:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, -592.520775623vmin);
}
section:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, -1722.423093745vmin);
}
section:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, -4695.850246699vmin);
}
section:nth-child(6) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, -12520.658543944vmin);
}
section:nth-child(1) *:not(.empty) {
  background-color: rgba(70, 130, 180, .5)
}
section:nth-child(2) *:not(.empty) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, .5)
}
section:nth-child(3) *:not(.empty) {
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 128, .5)
}
section:nth-child(4) *:not(.empty) {
  background-color: rgba(70, 130, 180, .5)
}
section:nth-child(5) *:not(.empty) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, .5)
}
section:nth-child(6) *:not(.empty) {
  background-color: rgba(128, 0, 128, .5)
}
header {
  height: 38%;
  width: 100%;
}
aside,
div {
  height: 38%;
  width: 31%;
  float: left;
}
div {
  width: 38%;
  background-color: transparent;
}
footer {
  clear: left;
  height: 24%;
  width: 100%;
}
#scroll {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section>
      <header></header>
      <aside></aside>
      <div class="empty"></div>
      <aside></aside>
      <footer></footer>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header></header>
      <aside></aside>
      <div class="empty"></div>
      <aside></aside>
      <footer></footer>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header></header>
      <aside></aside>
      <div class="empty"></div>
      <aside></aside>
      <footer></footer>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header></header>
      <aside></aside>
      <div class="empty"></div>
      <aside></aside>
      <footer></footer>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header></header>
      <aside></aside>
      <div class="empty"></div>
      <aside></aside>
      <footer></footer>
    </section>
  </main>
  <div id="scroll"></div>
</body>
```

The problem is that I can't manage the translateZ to make the whole thing move straight, it goes somewhat down (at an angle with the z axis). Even with the `perspective-origin: center center` on the body (instead of the current value).

Anyone has an idea of what's going on?

The effect I'm trying to achieve can be seen here: http://2011.beercamp.com/

But on my attempt the scroll zooms down (it should go go straight to through all the "windows"): [image]